# Чи є діалектизмом "То є" замість "це"/"таке"?

Tags: етимологія, діалектизми

Мене дивує, що в інтернеті ніколи не стояло питання щодо відмінностей цих конструкцій, які очевидно значать одне й те ж.

Приклади вживання з усного мовлення:

1. "Що таке?"/"Що є?" (у знач. що коїться?)
2. "Що таке метафора?"/"Що є метафора?"
3. "Що це таке?"/"Що то є?"
4. "Метафора це"/"Метафора є"

Як видно, при вживанні дієслова "бути" в особовій формі "є" після йде слово в називному відмінку.

Як приклади з писемного мовлення наведу декілька пісень:

пісня Володимира Івасюка - Червона рута:

```
Бо твоя врода
То є чистая вода
То є бистрая вода
З синіх гір
```

Трио Маренич - Ой там на горі:

```
Не думай милий, голубе сивий,
Що любов, то є жартоньки.
```

і вся пісня Кузьми Скрябіна "То є Львів".

До того ж, на відміну від "то є", конструкція (таке/це) зафіксована в академічного тлумачному словнику української мови (СУМ):

> 5. означ. У поєднанні з питальними займенниками хто, що, який та ін. утворює складне питання, вказуючи: а) на особу чи предмет, про які запитують. [Дівчина:] А хто вона така? [Хлопець:] Моя товаришка з дитячих літ (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 97); Щорс оглянув лави полонених суворим гнівним поглядом. — Звідки? Хто такі будете?.. (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 161); Як діти всі, він був цікавий,.. Про все питав: «Це що таке?» (Володимир Сосюра, II, 1958, 433); б) на суть предмета, явища тощо, про які запитують; що значить, що являє собою. «Ти не маєш права схибити. Ти мусиш завжди діяти безпомилково». Що таке безпомилково? (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 367); Він [Блюм] цікавий знати, хто такий Фраєрман (Петро Колесник, На фронті.., 1959, 120); — Хочеться мені перед боєм, сказати вам, панове, що таке є наше товариство (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 258);

> // Уживається як вказівне слово на межі двох речень, з яких друге містить у собі тлумачення, роз'яснення першого. На постелі лежала слаба жінка і стогнала. Це Харитина мати (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 13); — По копі з шагом... більше не можна дати [за хліб].. — Це, Овраме, — каже Лушня, — за таку ціну ти ніде не купиш (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 266); У загоні саме воли заборюкались — це старий підручний отих, що з ярмарку пригнали, б'є (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 145); — Чуєш, як сніг рипить? Це вершники — брати мої линуть мене виручати (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 59); — Гляньте-но, скільки в'юнів наловили. — Та все один в один, — дивується і водночас підхвалює рибалок Левко. — Це талан треба мати (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 77).

Отже, мої питання:
Чи можна таку конструкцію вважати діалектизмом? Чи є вона нормативною? Якщо це діалектизм, то яку має розповсюдженість?

Comment: Одне питання за раз. В поточному форматі, таке SE запитання, яке містить більше одного питання, відповідає одному із критеріїв закриття SE питання за що я голосую.

Comment: Так, бажано ставити лише одне питаннје, бо тут просле̂дковујитј сја: најавно̂стј _бути_ чи [взајмоде̂ја](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine4-11.pdf) _бути_ з іменниками в називному?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мій допис не дуже відповідає на те, чи є «то є» діалектизмом.

Я радше намагаюся переконати, що «то є», «це», «таке» й т.ін. — це не якісь взаємовиключні альтернативи, а радше фрагменти однієї і тої самої загальної «мозаїки». З «мозаїки» можна викидати один чи кілька елементів, і найчастіше так і роблять (щоб скоротити речення), але водночас не можна викинути надто багато елементів (тому в залежності від того, які елементи лишилися, маємо різні варіанти). Але всі варіанти, на мій погляд, більш-менш природні для української мови.

Я вбачаю дві «базові конструкції», які я надалі умовно називатиму одинарною і подвійною. (Це не загальноприйнята термінологія, і загалом, це моє власне бачення, а не загальноприйняте.)

#### «Одинарна» конструкція

*<А> є <Б>*. Інакше кажучи: *<Хтось/щось> є <хтось/щось (якесь)>.* Наприклад:

> …Бо кохання є джерело всього доброго (Борис Грінченко, «Сонячний промінь», 1890).
>
> Ся чудернацька мова є мішанина української мови з великоруськими словами… (Іван Нечуй-Левицький, «Українство на літературних позвах з Московщиною», 1891).

<sub>Ще є варіант з орудним відмінком — *<Хтось/щось> є <чимось/кимось (якимось)>*, наприклад «…Всякий видаток є гріхом, без котрого можна обійтися…» (Іван Франко, «Не спитавши броду», 1886), — але його я в цій відповіді розглядати не буду, бо це майже поза темою запитання. (Загалом я вважаю варіант з о.в. певною мірою синонімічним варіанту з н.в., але зазвичай о.в. використовують для зазначення менш постійної ознаки.) Надалі писатиму просто *<А> є <Б>*, але матиму на увазі саме називний відмінок у *<Б>*.</sub>

Тут усе просто:
[image: <А> — підмет, є <Б> — складений іменний присудок (а разом це просте двоскладне речення)]

#### «Подвійна» конструкція

*<А> — це/то є <Б>.* Наприклад:

> Національна свідомість, національне чуття — це є вже абстракція часової реальности… (Володимир Винниченко, «Відродження нації», 1920).
>
> …Чесна дівчина — то є краса і честь усього села (Марко Кропивницький, «Дай серцеві волю, заведе у неволю», 1882).

Мабуть, мої погляди відрізняються від загальноприйнятих, але я особисто вважаю, що принаймні формально можна трактувати цю конструкцію отак:
[image: як складне речення, що складається з двох простих: перед тире односкладне (лише з підметом) речення <А>, воно задає контекст, а після тире повноцінне (двоскладне) речення це/то є <Б>, у якому це/то — підмет, а є <Б> — (складений іменний) присудок]

Замість тире, між двома частинами (які я особисто інтерпретую як окремі прості речення) може стояти й інший знак, наприклад:

> Єдина держава, яка могла би помогти навіть вїйськом, *це є Ґерманія* (Володимир Винниченко, «Українська державність», 1920).
>
> Прага — дуже красне місто; *це є серце Чехії*… (Василь Королів-Старий, «Чмелик», 1920).
>
> Але сотні тисяч! Але мільйони!! *То вже не вороги народу. То є народ! Народ!* (Іван Багряний, «Сад гетсиманський», 1950).

#### Випадіння

І в тому варіанті, що я називаю «одинарним», і в тому варіанті, що я називаю «подвійним», може випадати *є*. Також у «подвійному» варіанті може випадати *це/то*.

Тоді отримуємо (можливо, звичніші для сучасного вуха) підваріанти:

- *<А> <Б>.* Наприклад:

  > Ви пан, а я сирота… (Іван Котляревський, «Наталка Полтавка», 1819).
- *<А> — це/то <Б>.* Наприклад:

  > Пастрама — це сушена баранина… (Олекса Стороженко, «Споминки про Микиту Леонтійовича Коржа», 1863).
  >
  > …Серце — то його корінь (Микола Устиянович, «Старий Єфрем», 1849).
- *<А> — <Б>.* Наприклад:

  > Наталка — по всьому полтавка, Петро — полтавець… (Іван Котляревський, «Наталка Полтавка», 1819).

(Часто кажуть, що пауза й, відповідно, тире з'явилися на місці випадіння *є*, але мені інтуїтивно більш подобаються шляхи «<А> є <Б>» → «<А> <Б>» й окремо «<А> — це/то є <Б>» → «<А> — це/то <Б>» → «<А> — <Б>», тобто що пауза й тире не з'являються на місці випадіння, а лишаються зі структури «подвійного» варіанта.)

#### Вказівні займенники

Також ніхто не забороняє починати *<Б>* з вказівного займенника на зразок *той/та/те/ті* чи *такий/така/таке/такі*. Часто так роблять, коли *<Б>* має залежне підрядне речення (і треба підкреслити, що воно [restrictive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness)); але необов'язково лише в цьому випадку. Багато прикладів наводити не буду:

> Я — *той* нещасний Петро, якому Наталка припівала сю пісню… (Іван Котляревський, «Наталка Полтавка», 1819).
>
> …Я *такий* невіглас (Джек Лондон у перекладі Катерини Джунківської, «Син сонця», 2019).

#### Питальні речення

Питальні речення мають приблизно ту саму структуру, тільки в основі *<Б>* може стояти питальний займенник на зразок *хто/що* (опціонально зі вказівним займенником на зразок *такий/така/таке/такі*, причому вказівний займенник може бути навіть не поряд з питальним):

- *Хто/що є <А>?* (Базова «одинарна» конструкція.)

  - *Хто/що <А>?* Наприклад: *Хто він?* (Випало *є*.)
  - *Хто/що такий/така/таке/такі є <А>?* (Додано *такий/така/таке/такі*.)

    - *Хто/що такий/така/таке/такі <А>?* (Випало *є*.)
- *Хто/що це/то є — <А>?* (Базова «подвійна» конструкція.)

  - *Хто/що це/то — <А>?* (Випало *є*.)
  - *Хто/що це/то є такий/така/таке/такі — <А>?* (Додано *такий/така/таке/такі*.)

    - *Хто/що це/то такий/така/таке/такі — <А>?* (Випало *є*.)

(Порядок слів може бути різний.)

#### Попередній висновок

Цією відповіддю я намагався переконати, що всі форми (зокрема й «то є») історично є більш-менш природними для української мови.

Але водночас нечесно було б не сказати, що навіть якщо щось історично було притаманне українській мові і, припустімо, побутувало на всіх теренах України, то з цього не випливає, що воно притаманне досі, причому всім регіонам однаково. Цілком може статися, що якісь із варіантів у якихось регіонах стали вживатися рідше, ніж в інших, або й зовсім набули статусу діалектних.

#### Тож діалектне чи ні?

Упевнено з цього приводу я можу небагато сказати, але, шукаючи приклади для цього допису, натрапив на [роботу Євгена Тимченка «Номінатив і датив в українській мові» (1925)](https://zbruc.eu/node/57967), де написано таке:

> Дієслово „бути" в теперішнім часі (пень єс-) в функції помічного дієслова в формі є, єсть (без огляду на лічбу й особу) ми подибуємо в таких випадках:
>
> 1. Коли треба протиставити два стани буття, напр.: Да не єсть то куна, то невіхна моя Чуб. IV, 436; не єсть ви козаки, а єсть ви гайдамаки Чуб. V, 243; ой не єсть ти удова, єсть ти вірная жена Черн. г. Чуб. V, 816.
> 2. В питайних і релятивних реченнях з присудковими: хто, що, який, чий, де, напр.: Хто він є? Полт. п.; що-ж він таке є? Мил. Жлк. 34; що ти є? Шух. Гуц. V, 1, здорові були свині! а чиї ви єсть? Рудч. Ск. І, 5. — Де ви є? — Що вам є?
> 3. В західніх говірках подибується часом як спійка між підметом і присудковим речівником або прикметником, напр.: Той пан, то є опришок Kolb. Р. IV, 55; Ой доле людськая! Доля єсть сліпая Закр. 73.
>
> Ст. р.: Се бо єсть батъгъ Божии Ип. 213.
>
> <Далі багато прикладів з випадінням дієслова *є* і багато цікавого про хитання між називним і орудним відмінками.>

Тобто: Євген Тимченко вважає, що використання дієслова *бути* в теперішньому часі (тобто *є*) притаманне західним говіркам, а також специфічним випадкам (як-от: протиставлення, питання).

#### *Є* (і *то є*) у словнику

Використання дієслова *бути* як зв'язки в складеному присудку зазначено 10-м пунктом відповідних статей у [СУМ-20](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=6191&page=226) і [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/buty). Але при цьому там кажуть, що «форма теперішнього часу *є*, *єсть* часто опускається», і єдиний там приклад з теперішнім часом — це «що сам єси тепер москаль» Шевченка.

Водночас *є* неодноразово використовується в цій ролі в прикладах, наприклад:

> Бо хвальба — то є [тлінь](http://sum.in.ua/s/tlinj), а від зради немає поради (Андрій Малишко, «Заповітне джерело», 1959).

Comment: Щиро дякую за таку ґрунтовну роботу! До речі, поки читав це, помітив ще, що навіть у наведених мною прикладах було вжито "є": "Хочеться мені перед боєм, сказати вам, панове, що таке є наше товариство (Олександр Довженко)".
Чесно кажучи, не знав, що "то" й "це" — синонимі. Багато нового дізнався з цього допису, дякую.

Comment: @whatserface, дякую. (_Це_, _то_ — не те щоб повні синоніми, але вони наче утворюють пару… От як є [«ближчі» і «дальші» вказівні займенники (_цей_, _ця_ (_цяя_), _це_ (_цеє_), _ці_ (_ції_) і _той_, _та_ (_тая_), _те_ (_теє_, _тоє_, _то_), _ті_ (_тії_) відповідно)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53410/25940.html), так є (етимологічно пов'язані з ними) «ближча» і «дальша» частки: _це_ і _то_. Хоча коли ми використовуємо їх як частки, то ми зазвичай не протиставляємо близьке і далеке, а просто вказуємо, тож великої різниці немає, радше просто звичка.)

Comment: (І _то_ ще може використовуватися як сполучник (наприклад: _якщо <якась умова>, то <якийсь наслідок>_), а от _це_ — вже ні.)